# POSTGRES - SELECT * FROM table WERE id = doesn't return any value but exists on the table

Tags: postgresql, navicat

I have table with some data I filled by transferring with Navicat.

But when I search by the primary key (id):

```
SELECT id,code FROM accounts WHERE id = 211;

  id | code
 ----+------

 (0 rows)
```

No rows, but if i search by another column:

```
SELECT id,code FROM accounts WHERE code = '51325';

  id  | code
 -----+-------  
  211 | 51325 
(1 row)
```

It returns the one with the id I want.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version (`select version();` will tell you). Does a `reindex accounts` fix this?

Comment: whats the type of your id column? Try WHERE id = '211'

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name reindexing works excellent thank you!!!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh wow, under what circumstances could this happen?! o_O

Comment: I used the navicat data sync feature can't understand why inserts without being indexed

Comment: Again: what is your exact postgres version? The fact that `reindex` solves this problem suggests that you are using an outdated version - there have been seem bugs around that, but they are all fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Reindexing the table make the query work!

```
REINDEX TABLE accounts;
```

Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name !!!